# Web based method to get public key from .pem file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, google-chrome-os

I have created an EC2 instance and I now want to connect to it from a Chromebook. For the time being, I only have access to this Chromebook and I am after a way of generating my public key from the .pem file that Amazon issues.

I am familiar with how to do this via the Linux command line, but I need a **web based** solution for this.

Comment: You don't need the public key to access an instance.  The public key is *on* the instance.  You need the private key, which is what's already in the .pem file... so it isn't clear what problem you need to solve, here.

Comment: Apparently I do https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/FAQ.md#Can-I-connect-using-a-public-key-pair-or-certificate

Comment: Wow.  Okay, I guess that techically would save CPU time on each connection if you just kept a copy laying around, but what a strange constraint.  So, we are both correct.  The pem file actually contains all the necessary info but your environment requires the info be split into two files.  Is the problem here the fact that you have zero access to any Unix or Windows computer you could use to extract the keys from the pem file?

Answer (score -1):

You need an SSH client for Chrome, try this: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo

Comment: thanks, but this is not the problem. The issue is creating the public key for it to connect to the instance.

Comment: To generate the public key you need a terminal (at least the unix way), so it could be useful to install the ssh extension for chrome.

Comment: I have it installed, but I cannot connect to the EC2 instance without the public key.

Comment: Received. Look at the following site (last anwser), I think it could be useful for your case: http://superuser.com/questions/867023/generation-of-ssh-keygen-in-chrome-os

Comment: thanks, had not seen that article. However, I am on a managed Chromebook and unable to enter Dev mode.

Comment: Sorry then I have no other solution for you :_(, I hope you find something useful for your case.